# Leer los datos de una tabla mostrando únicamente la primera vez que se logean los usuarios cada día

Tags: php, mysql

Ésta es la sintaxis de  la dos tablas que debe leer el código:

```
SELECT
  full_name,
  pass,
  event,
  event_date,
  server_ip,
  computer_ip
FROM asterisk.vicidial_users
INNER JOIN asterisk.vicidial_user_log
ON vicidial_users.user=vicidial_user_log.user
WHERE event_date BETWEEN '$START_DATE' AND '$END_DATE'
ORDER BY event_date ASC;
```

Pero esto me arroja todos los eventos y solo necesito el primero por cada usuario. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que tendrías que hacer es agrupar los datos por el campo que querés que sea único, en este caso, el nombre de usuario (*full_name*) y luego utilizar la función MIN para indicarle a motor de BBDD que querés de ese grupo el registro con el valor más chico en determinado campo (*event_date*).

```
SELECT full_name, pass, event, MIN(event_date), server_ip, computer_ip
FROM asterisk.vicidial_users
INNER JOIN asterisk.vicidial_user_log ON vicidial_users.user=vicidial_user_log.user
WHERE event_date BETWEEN '$START_DATE' AND '$END_DATE'
GROUP BY full_name
ORDER BY event_date ASC;
```

Comment: gracias por responder pero no hace exactamente lo que se requiere

Comment: este es el codigo con algunas correcciones SELECT full_name, pass, event, MIN(event_date), server_ip, computer_ip      FROM asterisk.vicidial_users INNER JOIN asterisk.vicidial_user_log ON vicidial_users.user=vicidial_user_log.user WHERE (vicidial_user_log.event= 'LOGIN') AND event_date BETWEEN '$START_DATE' AND '$END_DATE' ORDER BY event_date ASC.

Comment: el problema es que me jala un solo evento y uno por cada usuario, si tengo 3 usuarios me debe arrojar la primera ves que ellos se loguearon en el día

Comment: Creo que ahora entendí lo que decís. Los datos registrados en la tabla no son únicamente de login sino que hay distintos tipos de evento. Entonces lo que te estaría faltando es filtrar la tabla por eventos del tipo login para que el ordenado te lo haga únicamente a partir de estos.

Comment: El cómo hacer ese filtrado depende de cómo almacene tu sistema dicho eventos aunque por los nombres de los campos deduzco que deberías agregar al WHERE una condición contra el campo event.

Comment: buenos dias, te indico. el campo event guarda el login y el logout por cada ves que el usuario se conecta y desconecta, eso quiere decir que esa tabla guardara el evento cuantas veces pace en el dia, yo solo quiero que me muestre en pantalla la primera ves que ingrese el usuario en el día, algo así como una asistencia yo ya limite la busqueda a (vicidial_user_log.event= 'LOGIN') con esto solo me busca los inicios de secion pero me trae todos los del día y me tiene que traer es uno por cada usuario. si son 20 usuarios que me muestre el primer Login del dia de cada usuario